# How to trigger angular ng click using non-Angular javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have element like this :

```
<button ng-click="xyzfunction.vote(true)" class="primary">
```

I want to trigger the function specified in `ng-click` attribute from outside of the world of Angular. How could I do this?

I cannot just call `xyzfunction.vote(true)`, clearly, as it is not defined globally. But it is defined somewhere (in some controller). How can I call it?

**For broader context:** I want to call this function in a Greasemonkey script

Comment: Your question is very very bad phrased. First, you forgot to add the AngularJS tag, I add it and I try to answer your question, then, you also forgot to add you want an answer in the Greasemonkey environment...

Comment: So this isn't about angular or `ng-click`, but how to trigger a button on an HTML page from Greasemonkey?

Comment: i cannot call : xyzfuncation.vote(true) from script

Comment: @Claies, I actually think it is about Angular, although the request is to trigger a scope-defined function from outside of Angular - I edited the question text and voted to re-open

Answer (score 0):

You can get the scope from outside angular using `angular.element` and `$scope`:

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".controller-element");
angular.element(elem).$scope().xyzfunction.vote();
```

Ofc `.controller` needs to be substituted with a selector that resolves to an element that has the corresponding scope.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have following html:

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="MyController" id="MyContainer"></div>
```

Then perform following way to access your function of controller from outside the angular scope.

```
angular.element('#MyContainer').scope().yourFunction();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a global object keeping the function and reuse it in angular and greasemonkey:

**mynamespace.js:**

```
var MYNAMESPACE = {
  xyzfunction: {
    vote: function (boolan) {
      // your vote function here
    }
  }
}
```

**mynamespaceFactory.js**

```
angular.module('myapp', []).factory('MyNameSpace', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return $window.MYNAMESPACE;
}]);
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('YourController', ['MyNameSpace', function (MyNameSpace) {
   $scope.xyzfunction = MyNameSpace.xyzfunction;
}]);
```

**greasemonkey.js:**

```
MYNAMESPACE.xyzfunction.vote(true);
```

To improve on this, use a robust [namespacing pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailnamespacing) to create your global object.